# what's causing this loop to go out of bounds?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a word find game and can't find why the while loop is giving me `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error. The error says it is in this line: `grid[i-1][j-1]=kb.next();`    but I can't see why?

[image: Code screen shot]

Comment: For next time, just paste your code directly here; it's much better than a screenshot.

Comment: haha I have figured that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple logic error. You are not resetting the value of j after you come out of while loop (j <= width). As a result for next value of i the value of j starts from the last possible index value and not from 0.

Reset j to 1 everytime you come increment value of i after while loop.

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't see that.  Staring at the screen to long I guess.  Thanks, that was definitely the main hang-up.

Answer (score 3):

*(You should have posted your code)* but, your while loop is going till:

```
while(i<=height)
```

and

```
while(i<=widht)
```

They should be

`while(i < height)` and `while(i < width)`

Since the array index starts with `0` and will continue to `Length - 1`, *(Also you need to reset `j` value after coming out of inner loop)*

Comment: @Downvoter, I would appreciate if you can point to the mistake

Comment: @howlowworld, yes You have to, but, they exception you were getting was due to this condition

Answer (score 1):

Looping over 1 to width (or height) is fine, if not standard practice, since you index with [i-1] or [j-1].

What your screen capture doesn't show is what the user (you, I assume) entered for "Enter width of grid".  Was it the same number for each, or different?   Did you get the first and second indexes switched around?

Comment: I entered 4 for width and 3 for height